# Desencriptando data

Tags: php, data, timestamp

Eu tenho um painel, e ele encripta a data, e queria saber como eu posso desencriptar para mostrar no meu site.

Data encriptada: 1437619904

Queria colocar para a forma normal.

Comment: E o metodo de encriptacao qual é?

Comment: Isso não é encriptada é a data em segundos desde 1970, veja aqui: http://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: Essa data é `Qui 23 Jul 2015 03:51:44 WEST GMT+1:00 DST`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso é a data gerada pela função [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.time.php).

> Retorna a hora atual medida no número de segundos desde a Era Unix
>   (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

Podes converter para data normal usando a função [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php):

```
echo date('m/d/Y H:i:s', 1437619904);
```

Comment: Olá Jorge, é que tipo, eu queria puxar a data da database, se eu utlizar esse código eu posso puxar da database essa data da função time e colocar no modo que você organizou?

Comment: Sim, vais buscar a base de dados, colocas numa variável por exemplo `$data_bd` e usas:  `$data_normal = date('m/d/Y H:i:s', $data_bd);`

Comment: Jorge, tem como eu colocar "$noticias['data']" ou algo do tipo em $data_bd? Pois eu tentei e deu erro, algo que possa resolver?

Comment: @Kloves `$data_bd = $noticias['data']; date('m/d/Y H:i:s', $data_bd);`

Comment: Jorge, deu esse seguinte erro: Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered

Comment: @Kloves tens a certeza que vem `1437619904` da variável `$noticias['data']`?

Comment: Jorge eu coloquei "echo" no antes de "$data_db" e apareceu só a data, o horário não apareceu e continuou aquele erro. E tenho certeza sim.

Comment: @Kloves faz `echo $noticias['data']` o que imprime?

Comment: Eu tirei o echo de lá e fiz isso que você mandou só que continuou com a função time.

Comment: Olá Jorge, já resolvi, só resta uma coisa, tem como eu colocar assim: Dia "tal' às "horário"? Código: <?php 

$data_bd = $edit['data'];

$data_atual = date('m/d/Y H:m:s', $data_bd); ?>

Comment: @Kloves `$data_atual = date('m/d/Y', $data_bd); $hora_atual = date('H:m:s', $data_bd); echo "Dia $data_atual  ás $hora_atual";`

Comment: Eu me logo, mas não consigo falar na conversa.

Comment: Deu tudo certo, obrigado!

Comment: @Kloves de nada ainda bem que ajudei :)